# Potentially redundant files?

Tags: uninstall, visual-studio-2010

I have a machine that runs Visual Studio 2010 only for C++, however when I open *Programs and Features* there are a lot of files:

[image]

that have remained from previous versions and I find it difficult to discern which is absolutely necessary and which could be removed.

The machine is used for exercise in programming nothing of particular significance could be broken.

My thought is to remove everything and update to Visual Studio 2015, is that a good idea?

How could I figure out what to remove?

### Edit:

Apparently this is a huge issue with VS products and their remaining outdated dependencies versions:

http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3487794-create-a-remove-all-remnants-of-visual-studio-fro

All this started because I couldn't install Visual Studio Community 2015 in any mode and under any state of the machine.

---

P.S.: Nothing personal against Windows, but after 2-3 days and more than 45 hours I can't install Visual Studio Community 2015 and the only option seems to be switching to Linux.

Comment: I don't see any redundant files in your screenshot.  Programs can require specific versions of the redistributable.  Are you really worried about a couple hundred megabytes?

Comment: Those are different versions, and they were installed, by the program that required them.  If you uninstall them those programs that require those specific versions wil stop functioning

Answer (score 1):

First off, you don't *have to* uninstall VS 2010 in order to install VS 2015 (unless you really run out of disk space). Different versions of Visual Studio can all be installed and used side-by-side.

Now onto the actual question, what the snapshot shows is mostly runtime packages of different versions of the CRT/MFC libraries and SQL tools. Some of those don't even come with VS 2010, and *any* of those could have been installed by some 3rd party app that requires it. Uninstalling indiscriminately will most likely break something unrelated to VS 2010. Plus, if you look at the sizes on disk, you won't get much space back, anyway.

A few of those (and I am thinking primarily at Tools for Office) *may* have been installed along VS 2010 if you chose the "*typical*" install. If you only care about C++, then always select "*custom*" install, where you can pick and choose what exactly gets installed.